# Why do we return Live Data from the repository? (MVVM Android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

Many examples return LiveData from the repository to the ViewModel

```
public class Repository{

    private fun getText(): LiveData<String> = FakeDataBase.text
}
```

But does it make a difference if we just return String and set the returned Data into the LiveData in the ViewModel?

For example when we use Retrofit we get a Call Object back and mostly we cast the call object into LiveData with special classes. So we can just skip the step and get the value from the Call Object, return it in the ViewModel and set the value into the LiveData in ViewModel

Answer (score 3):

Problem is when your repository is doing some time-consuming task.
If you would simply wait for it to finish your   ViewModel  would be blocked for that time period.  When repository returns LiveData object it is actually a contract  that states "When I get the data I will inform you if you subscribe to me". It will run time consuming task on a different thread when finished it will update its LiveData object and all observers will be notified. 
Real benefit comes if you need same data from repository in different ViewModels, every ViewModel will simply subscribe to same LiveData object.

Answer (score 0):

Many examples that I see around don't use LiveData to communicate from the Repository back to the ViewModel, including the ones on Google's architecture samples:

[Android Architecture Blueprints v2](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/tree/master)

More and more often I can see people wrapping data in custom Result classes like the ones in this example.

So there is not a correct response to your question, it will depend on what you want to do. LiveData is all about the observable pattern (with lifecycle support), is there something posting values to this LiveData? Or you are just doing  synchronous operations (you mentioned retrofit calls)? If it's the last case, you are safe just returning the string.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies on the functional programming paradigm. In more complex cases you want to start applying operators on this result you just fetch. Let's say you want to fetch from another service data based on you result then append success at the end.
In functional style it will look like:

```
repo.fetchResult()
  .flatMap { repo2.fetchSecondResultById(it) }
  .map { it.concat("success") }
```

This is just a simple sample, it can get way worse depending on your business case. Off course there are many more operators in functional libraries that would help with more complex cases.
Now, where LiveData comes in.
LiveData was Google attempt to make a reactive implementation. But later on, they realized that RxJava was so heavily used that they decided not to continue the effort. At the same time Kotlin was gaining attraction in Android. Kotlin comes with Coroutines and Flow which is another reactive library too. Then Google to not fragmenting the ecosystem even more decided to dump the LiveData effort and it just remains in old samples or when you want to deliver an event from the ViewModel to the View.

But the efforts for making LiveData chainable or functional rest on the sea. Use Flow or RxJava.
Your repo should return a Single or an Observable or a Flow.